# java code--how to detect if a browser is opened

Tags: java, browser, detect

I would like to know any java method can be used to check if the browser is closed.

I used the following code to open a default browser:

```
if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported()){
     Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
     desktop.browse(new URI(url));
}
```

Then I want to perform some user actions on the opened website to capture the web traffic. After the browser is closed the web traffic will be saved.

So how can I determine if the browser is closed by using java code?

Comment: I don't think you can do that...

Comment: See this: http://beradrian.wordpress.com/2008/11/03/detecting-process-exit-in-java/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do is use Process builder:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe");
        Process p1 = pb.start();
        p1.waitFor();
        System.out.println(p1.exitValue());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print(e);
    }
}

}
```

You can launch a browser with the webpage as an argument and keep track of it like that.